# Ask FBI permission to withdraw large sums from your checking or savings?

Tags: united-states, withdrawal

Is it true you have to file papers with the government in the US to withdraw large sums of cash at your local bank branch? I read somewhere once if it's over $5,000.00 somewhere you have to file papers with the FBI and wait. What if I wanted to withdraw $30,000.00 one day at my local branch, or even $4,000,000.00(where I had millions spread across banks for protection)?

Comment: Since I'm not from the US I cannot answer it for sure, if I'm not wrong its just the bank that needs to confirm you got the money on legal (or plausible) ways.

Comment: Have you tried calling your bank and asking? What did they say?

Comment: I think reading [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/50650/45435) to a similar question may be helpful for you

Comment: Oddly enough I did this today in order to get a cashier's check for the purchase of a car.  There was nothing to it, it would have taken the same amount of time if I was getting a cashier's check for $20.

Comment: On a related note, in such cases you might need to inform the branch beforehand - in general, banks don't keep very large amounts of cash in branches and for sufficiently large amounts you'd  need to schedule that so that they'd drive enough cash there for you.

Comment: It saddens me that this question needs to be asked.  "Is it OK if I want to get MY OWN money out of the bank or do I need to ask the government for permission and wait for a response?"

Comment: @Bart It's not "your money", it's a bank deposit. Don't like it, don't use the bank, you will gain the ability to do whatever you want with your own money, among other benefits, but also lose some like security against theft, online transfers or FDIC insurance.

Comment: saw this on the Hot Network List and thought someone was checking if there was some truth to a spam email

Comment: @PeteB. About the only difference is that if the amount is large enough, the teller may need to get an additional approval. If your teller happened to be a manager, then an additional approval might not have been needed. This is to ensure a few things: 1) The teller and you aren't conspiring to withdraw someone else's money. 2) You aren't being coerced. 3) The appropriate identity checks were done.

Comment: @Superbest it certainly is your money.  However a bank relationship is a relationship, especially at the $30k tier, and you have to work with your relationship partner. Expecting them to keep $30k cash just sitting there all the time is not realistic unless you make that prearrangement.  Asking them to disregard their legal "Know Your Customer" and reportage obligations is also not gonna happen. Being able to "just grab $500k" to pay [the vacuum cleaner repairman](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Ed) is the advantage of the Bank of the Water Heater.

Comment: @Superbest, funny that you include FDIC insurance in the benefits I am losing... since FDIC insurance only applies to the specific problem of a bank failing

Comment: @Harper bitcoin gives you some of the same benefits of the Bank of the Water Heater (i.e. not needing permission to get ahold of your own money) without the risk of a thief breaking into your house stealing it

Comment: @Bart it seems to have its own security problems though.  It helps to be good at keeping data alive without letting it get compromised.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is it true you have to file papers with the government in the US to
>   withdraw large sums of cash at your local bank branch?

It's true that a currency transaction report (CTR) gets filed with FinCEN (Financial Crimes Enforcement Network) when you make a cash transaction in excess of $10,000. Banks have systems that do this automatically, so you don't have to really do anything other than provide some tax info if not already on file with the bank.

The teller can flag your CTR if they think the transaction is suspicious, but there shouldn't be a delay on the withdrawal unless the bank has to make arrangements to have enough cash on hand.

Some people don't like the idea of CTR's being filed and therefore make multiple smaller withdrawals, but that can be considered illegal structuring, and can result in confiscated money.

Comment: Yeah CTR is what I read about too, and very large sums need an advance notice for reserve transfer.

Comment: Actuallly, banks file the CTR even faster if several small withdrawals are placed. There are automated systems to detect that as part of the money laundering effort. Then there are several other controls after that trigger to verify if it is indeed a money laundering attempt. You should put a source to this "confiscated money" thing, if that is true. The bank will only lock down the account as far as I know, pending a money laundering audit. And that is the extreme case.

Comment: @Mindwin The extreme case is the government seizing funds: https://www.money-education.com/resources/financial-planning-news-and-blogs/blog/129-structuring-cash-transactions-under-10-000-is-criminal

Comment: @HartCO yeah. After the money laundering audit is through, and there is reasonable cause to believe money laundering is at work. **disclosure** I work at a major global bank.

Comment: @Mindwin Structuring itself is illegal, you don't have to be laundering money to be guilty of intentionally dodging BSA reporting requirements (like example of farmer in article). Also, money being seized after an audit that you didn't know was happening is still disruptive and their "reasonable cause" turns up plenty of false positives. It's good note for business owners that deal in cash, establish a relationship with a bank so you minimize chances of getting flagged.

Comment: If they seize your cash, they [may not give it back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States), even if they are unable to prove you broke any laws.

Comment: It is illegal structuring withdrawing MY money? beautiful

Comment: @HartCO According to [this article](http://www.baltimoresun.com/news/maryland/politics/blog/bal-maryland-dairy-farmer-randy-sowers-will-have-seized-money-returned-20160629-story.html), they eventually got their money back.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's illegal **if** it's for the purpose of dodging CTR and other AML reporting.

Comment: @xiaomy It was a rhetoric question...as soon you deposit money in the bank it obviously stop being *your* money, moreover with laws and controls like this.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Oh I see. Well, it's either that or cash, which probably will be outlawed at some point. :/

Comment: @xiaomy I heard they still settled on a payment of $30k, can't check your article atm. Either way, they like to act first and then ask questions, which can be a pretty big hassle even when they do clear things up. I bet it's a smoother process now, but I'm sure innocent folks are still hassled from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

An international Outlook (in this case Sweden in European Union).

According to laws and regulations large cash transactions are considered conspicuous. The law makers might have reasoned is that cash transactions can be used in as example:
- financing terrorism
- avoiding taxes
- buying or selling illegal goods such as drugs or stolen items
- general illegal transactions such as paying bribes

Starting there, all banks (at least in Europe) are required to report all suspicious transactions to the relevant authorities (in Sweden it is Finanspolisen, roughly the Financial Police). This is regardless of how the transactions are performed, in cash or otherwise. In order to monitor this all banks in Sweden are required to "know the customers", as example where does money come from and go to in general. In addition special software monitors all transactions and flags suspicious patterns for further investigation and possibly notification of the police.

So, at least in Sweden: there is no need to get permission from the FBI to withdraw cash. You will however be required to describe the usage of the Money and your description will be kept and possibly sent to the Financial police.

The purpose is not to hinder legitimate transactions, but to Catch illegal activities.

Comment: But how would they  detect if it was to buy a house or car, or to pay off blackmail or a hostage situation?

Comment: The purpose of it is to tighten the net on tax evasion and the middle class sending money to offshore operations. And also to rob you via a 10/20 year span with a interest near 0 or bellow inflation levels. Officials in the EC have been giving hints to the general public about plans for a decade of that.